# powershell script - TimeGenerated Last 24 hours

Tags: powershell

I have a functional PowerShell script that I'm using to capture user logons and logoffs for single local machine. The script works fine, but I'm having a difficult time trying to pull the last 24 hours from current date/time. I have `$Date = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-1)` at the top of my script, but it appears to be getting ignored.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

```
powershell
$Date = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-1)
$Date.tostring("MM-dd-yyyy_HH,mm,ss")
$UserProperty = @{n="user";e={(New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $_.ReplacementStrings[1]).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])}}
$TypeProperty = @{n="Action";e={if($_.EventID -eq 7001) {"Logon"} else {"Logoff"}}}
$TimeProperty = @{n="Time";e={TimeGenerated}}
Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon | select $UserProperty,$TypeProperty,$TimeProperty | export-csv -path C:\Temp\TrackLogin.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Where are you using the `$Date` variable in your script other than setting it and then formatting it with `.ToString()`?

Comment: I believe those are the only two location I had set. I did add `$Date` to `$TimeProperty`, but that just gave me the current time for every entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is very limited as it doesn't interact with the date at all. Here is a bit of code I use in a function. Should work if run as an admin.

```
$Days = 1
$Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$events = @()
$events += Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $Computer -FilterHashtable @{ 
    LogName='Security'
    Id=@(4800,4801)
    StartTime=(Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days) 
}

$events += Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $Computer -FilterHashtable @{ 
    LogName='System'
    Id=@(7001,7002)
    StartTime=(Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days) 
}

$type_lu = @{
    7001 = 'Logon'
    7002 = 'Logoff'
    4800 = 'Lock'
    4801 = 'Unlock'
}

$ns = @{'ns'='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'}
$target_xpath = "//ns:Data[@Name='TargetUserName']"
$usersid_xpath = "//ns:Data[@Name='UserSid']"

If($events) {
    $results = ForEach($event in $events) {
        $xml = $event.ToXml()
        Switch -Regex ($event.Id) {
            '4...' {
                $user = (Select-Xml -Content $xml -Namespace $ns -XPath $target_xpath).Node.'#text'
                Break            
            }
            '7...' {
                $sid = (Select-Xml -Content $xml -Namespace $ns -XPath $usersid_xpath).Node.'#text'
                $user = (New-Object -TypeName 'System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier' -ArgumentList $sid).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
                Break
            }
        }
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            Time = $event.TimeCreated
            Id = $event.Id
            Type = $type_lu[$event.Id]
            User = $user
        }
    }
    If($results) {
        $results | sort Time -Descending
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.